# `mode` option in ansible synchronize does not work

Tags: unix, ansible

I recently set up an ansible role with the task:

```
- name: "synchronize source"
  sudo: yes
  synchronize:
    src: "../../../../" # get source dir
    dest: "{{ app.user.home_folder }}/{{ app.name }}"
    mode: 700
```

Unfortunately, upon inspection, the transferred files have `-rw-r--r--`. Not a big deal, as I have set up another task to chmod the files, but I am wondering why this is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `mode` parameter for `syncronize` wrong. From Ansible's documentation:

> Mode specify the direction of the synchroniztion. In **push** mode the
>   localhost or delegate is the source; In **pull** mode the remote host in
>   context is the source.

What you are thinking of is `mode` parameter for the `copy` module. There it sets permissions.